# Which SQL Server edition is suitable for my development?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am going to develop a small inventory application using C# (VS 2010) and SQL Server. I should install this on 5 or 6 computers. I explored SQL Server 2012, it has many editions.

**I do not know, which edition is suitable for development, deploy and install in client place.**

Please help me..

Comment: You can use `Express Edition` since you have only 5-6 computers.

Comment: if you use less than 10GB of data, SQL Server Express should be sufficient. However, when deploying if you expect you database to increase rapidly and over the 10GB threshold then a different version will be required.

Comment: also keep in mind, it is not only memory restrictions in the various editions, some features like `indexed view matching` require Enterprise or Developer Edition

Comment: Why exactly SQL Server?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I should install this on 5 or 6 computers"? Do you have 5 or 6 clients, and you need to install a separate instance of the application+SQL server for each, or do you write the client in C#, install it on 5 or 6 computers in your organization, and make them all use a central SQL server? Also - do you need a central database for the client, or does each installation support one-user-at-a-time and uses a local SQL server?

Comment: Thanks to all.. @IdanArye In one client place I need to install 5 or 6 computers as central SQL server or central database and it should support all users at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install SQL Server on each user's computer. Just one copy on a server is enough.  At that scale, it is considered a "very small" app ("small" at my company ranges between 20 - 50 users). If so, use the Express editions. When you are bumping against its restrictions, you can always upgrade to Standard. The update process is really easy and straight forward.

If you don't want to invest in hardware, go to the cloud. Working with SQL Azure is, for the most part, similar to working with a local server.